CoreLocation module always fails to fetch my phone's real location accurately
The CoreLocation module always fails to fetch my phone's real location accurately, and the location shown by showUserLocation always has a slight deviation.
The code of LocationViewModel.swift
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @Published var location: Location?
    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?
    @Published var errorMessage: String?
    @Published var gpsSignalStatus: String = "Detecting GPS signal..."

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        checkAuthorizationStatus()
    }
    
    func checkAuthorizationStatus() {
        authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            errorMessage = "The authorization of location is limited。Please turn it on in settings"
        default:
            errorMessage = "Unknown location authorization status"
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkAuthorizationStatus()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.location = Location(
            coordinate: location.coordinate,
            altitude: location.altitude,
            speed: location.speed,
            direction: location.course,
            horizontalAccuracy: location.horizontalAccuracy,
            timestamp: location.timestamp
        )
        
        if location.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
            gpsSignalStatus = "GPS is not avaliable"
        } else if location.horizontalAccuracy > 100 {
            gpsSignalStatus = "GPS signal is weak."
        } else {
            gpsSignalStatus = "GPS signal is great."
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        if var currentLocation = self.location {
            currentLocation.direction = newHeading.trueHeading
            self.location = currentLocation
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to find user's location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

The code of LocationView.swift
...
struct MapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LocationViewModel
    
    @State var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(position: $cameraPosition) {
                if let coordinate = viewModel.location?.coordinate {
                    Annotation("MyLocation", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)) {
                        Text("The position which CoreLocation got")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .onReceive(viewModel.location.publisher) { location in
                cameraPosition = .region(MKCoordinateRegion(
                    center: location.coordinate,
                    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0025, longitudeDelta: 0.0025)
                ))
            }
        }
    }
}
...

The position obtained from CoreLocation has an error of several hundred meters compared to the actual position.

Any problem in my code?
Is there a way to obtain the right location?


Are you inside or outside?  In a city with tall buildings or in a valley or in open terrain?

Yesterday I was indoors, in a city. There was an error of about 500 meters between the location obtained based on CoreLocation and the actual displayed position of the blue dot on the iOS built-in Maps app. Today I am outdoors, but still in the city, and the error has been reduced to about 50 meters. If using MapKit's showUserLocation mode, the blue dot position obtained is also correct. I don't know why this is happening.

Those sound reasonable.  GPS needs signals from four or more satellites.  The signals are highly affected by building structures and also bounce off high-rise buildings resulting in inaccuracies.  I can't see anything wrong in your code.  The position you get should be identical to the position shown for the blue dot in maps

That's the strange part. Even in the same location, there's still a significant discrepancy between the blue dot position on the map and the position I get through CoreLocation. This error is unacceptable. How does Apple's Maps app get my accurate location? If CoreLocation cannot obtain a precise location, is there a way to get the accurate latitude and longitude of the blue dot?

I have never had a variation between core location and the location reported by Apple Maps.

I took your code and changed your Annotation to Marker and added a UserAnnotation - The two markers were on top of each other.

That's really strange. I'm not sure if it's related to me being in China. I'll ask other Chinese developers who work with maps to see what they think.

Anyway, no matter what the reason is, thank you very much for the help.
